# Can Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio run on macOS?

Tags: macos, sql-server, ssms

I know Microsoft SQL Server 2016 can run on macOS in a Docker container. But does can Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio run on macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is no.

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio can only run on Windows operating systems at this time: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms#supported-operating-systems.